# ADAL authentication without webview

Tags: ios, azure, adal

Can I authenticate user using adal for iOS (https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-objc) without webview being popped up ? Is there some API to which I can provide username/password and it returns me auth-token without user typing credentials ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Adal on mobile platforms does not provide mechanisms for using raw username and password directly. Once you performed the interactive authentication (and consent, mfa or anything else your azure ad settings require) you'll be able to function for a long time without prompting again, but that first step requires an experience that offers the opportunity to inject those extra steps. Also, this makes it possible to never disclose credentials directly to the app.

Comment: Can you confirm this. Maybe a reference from Microsoft?

Comment: How about with clientId and clientSecret

Comment: ClientID and Secret are for confidential clients, which can be trusted to protect secrets. Mobile app cannot, hence they are modeled as public clients. The mobile ADALs only offer auth mechanisms suitable for public clients, hence no clientID and secret flow.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using the broker mode. 
Check this link --> https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-objc#brokered-authentication

With the broker mode user will be prompted to authenticate using the Microsoft Authenticator App